# Scaled FloatingActionButton blurred in API 21

Tags: android, animation, scale, material-design, floating-action-button

I wanted to make a FloatingActionButton animate into bottom toolbar as in the Toolbar section of Material Design guide.

I am using a FloatingActionButton from official Support Design Library. I put the FAB in another layout, that would clip it when FAB gets scaled. I am using setScaleX() and setScaleY() on FAB, but run into a problem on different API versions.

Screens of problem (sorry for resolution, I didn't want to upscale it so you wouldn't miss the problem):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ0nR.jpg

In API 21 FAB is blurred as it gets scaledX/scaledY, and as the FAB fills the whole view random border, made from background starts flickering around (it is seen in the end screenshot).
None of that happens in other APIs, FAB is not blurred and fills correctly whole view, no background visible.

Tested on different resolutions, from 480x800 to 1200x1920 and on APIs from 16 to 22. What could be the problem? It that a bug in 21 version of Lollipop?

Comment: Any luck solving the issue? I just ran into same thing on API 21

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution :

I've decided to override layout with -v21 version where I created simple circle View with accent color. This view doesnt render at any other version of android, hidden below FAB and default visibility is GONE.

With FAB onClickListener I set the View visibility to visible, fab to GONE and run the animation on my created view instead. Again - this only happens on API 21. Other apis are not affected.

```
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final View fabAnimHelper = fL.findViewById(R.id.fab_anim_helper);
                    fabAnimHelper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fabAnimHelper.startAnimation(fabFill);
                } else {
                    fab.startAnimation(fabFill);
                }
```